# MySQL Server maxing out memory, Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel, memory-management, galera

I have PHP (**Laravel 5.7**) application connected to a cluster of DBs powered by Galera cluster. I am running cron job every night to clear thousands of thousands log data from DB tables. I run `Delete` statement of the MySQL to delete the rows in the table based on the time stamp range.

My Delete Operations looks like

```
DB::delete('DELETE FROM incoming_logs WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)');
DB::delete('DELETE FROM provisioning_logs WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '.Config::get('app.keep_provisioning_logs') .' DAY)');
```

**NOTE:** And these are defined in Laravel console commands and those commands scheduled in Laravel tasks.

**Problem:** 
Every time after running the cron job to delete the huge amount of data: `Main memory` of the DB servers max out and when I clear the cache memory manually using following command, I get my `Main Memory` free.

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I need to know about why cache is not being automatically re-claimed, or why after cron job my memory went out as well as I faced problem of `too many connection` error on MySQL.

Or is this just because my DB servers (**Total 3 DB servers** under load balancer and syncing using galena) syncing real time, so when i try to delete thousands records using cron job, the server which get that delete request try to delete and maintain cache to sync with other DBs? I am not sure whats going on. Please help me with my memory maxing out problem.

**My Architecture:** 
**One Load balancer** (HA proxy having three DBs under it) and **galera cluster** to sync data among those three DBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting half the table every night?  Consider deleting an hour's worth every hour.

Do you have `INDEX(created_at)`?  That would help the hourly purge, though perhaps not the daily purge.

This task is an excellent one for `PARTITIONing`.

These, and more techniques, are discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Comment: Yes I can delete every hour but the problem is thousands records in an hour and when i fire the delete statement one db pick up that request via HA proxy and that db cache those and try to make connection with other DBs on the cluster that max out the memory as well as giving me max connection on sql issue. Thanks for the link, let me try all the possibilities then

Comment: @webDev - What about deleting every minute?

Comment: okay let me first delete every hour and see how many dead lock issue i get. thanks. let me keep posting.

Comment: I think If i will be able to implement all the techniques discussed on the link you posted, my problem will be solved. Thank you very much for the link. I will mark this as answer when I will be done doing all the stuff mentioned in that document.

Comment: @webDev - As for why Galera has that hiccup -- I _think_ the answer is that it works better by doing smaller chunks of work at a time.  (Hence, my answer.)

Comment: Now I am getting dead lock issue or query interrupted issue. And this is because I think my architecture of the app and cluster behind the load balancer. Among three DBs, any one of them can get hit by several application randomly and if sync process delays that cause the dead lock problem.

Comment: @webDev - How many clients?  How is the proxy configured?  How many xactions/sec?  Is this xaction a long one?  Consider switching to logically a Master + 2 slaves (while still having Galera).